# Proving equality between two limsups

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

Say we have two bounded sequences $a_{n}, b_{n}$, where $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=1$. I have to prove that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_{n}b_{n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_{n}$.
My idea was as following: First $b_{n}$ is bounded, so we can denote $\limsup b_{n}=L$. There exists a sub-sequence of $b_{n}$, $b_{n_{k}}$ that satisfies $\lim b_{n_{k}}=L$.
Now we look at the sub-sequence of $a_{n}b_{n} - a_{n_{k}}b_{n_{k}}$. $\lim a_{n_{k}}=1$ as a sub-sequence of a converging sequence. So using limit arithmetic rules, $\lim a_{n_{k}}b_{n_{k}}=L=\limsup b_{n}$.

Now whats left is to prove that $\lim a_{n_{k}}b_{n_{k}}=\limsup a_{n}b_{n}$. Let's assume by contradiction that this is false. So there exists a sub-sequence $a_{n_{j}}b_{n_{j}}$ that satisfies $\lim a_{n_{j}}b_{n_{j}}=K, K>L$. $a_{n_{j}}$ converges to $1$ and $a_{n_{j}}b_{n_{j}}$ converges to $K$, so we can assume that $b_{n_{j}}$ converges to $K$, in contradiction to the assumption that $\limsup b_{n}=L$.

Is my argument correct or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks good to me. Maybe you should explain why it must be that $K \ge L$.

Comment: This is essentially correct, I think, although I think more detail in the second paragraph would help (certainly we don't want to "assume" that $b_{n_j}$ converges to $K$, we want to prove it). Another good way to proceed is to prove first that $\limsup a_nb_n \ge \limsup b_n$ and $\limsup b_n \ge \limsup a_nb_n$ separately. You're essentially doing this already; I just wanted to emphasize that this sort of splitting into two subgoals can really make strategies clearer (rather than feeling like we're stumbling into a solution).

Comment: You're absolutely right I meant prove not assumes. By the way why do you feel splitting it would be clearer? I feel like this problem is pretty straight-forward. I don't see how to split it personally